# How to change non selected annotation pin images on mapkit with Swift

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit

I have a map and on this map, I have 10 custom annotation pins. All pins have the same custom image. When I click on a pin, I need to change all the other 9 annotation's images. it's possible to change the clicked pin's image but I need to keep as it is and I need to change all other pins images.

I tried to get all annotations with Map `mapView.annotations` and tried to find selected annotations and change other images but couldn't manage it. And idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conform to `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol and then:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
    let selectedAnnotation = view.annotation
    for annotation in mapView.annotations {
        if let annotation = annotation as? MKAnnotation where !annotation.isEqual(selectedAnnotation) {
            // do some actions on non-selected annotations in 'annotation' var
        }
    }
```

Also you can save the selected annotation for later use here, if you want to process all annotations in another moment.

Comment: my comment was so long so i added it as answer, can you kindly check my post. Thank you

Comment: @marmaralone  will definitely try your code in the evening, too busy on my job now :(

Comment: solved the problem and explained how did i do it as a new answer, thank you for the tip ;)

Comment: @marmaralone  congrats on solving! sometimes it's necessary to brainstorm it a bit, because only you know preciously how it should look like at the end.

Comment: will u please write this for objective c also, thnx

Answer (score 1):

finally managed :) solved the problem little bit hard way but working smooth :) thank you for the tip rshev ;)

i used a bool for tap recognize

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is CustomAnnotation {
        var pin = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(customAnnotationViewIdentifier)
        pin = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: customAnnotationViewIdentifier)

        if tapControl {
            pin.image = UIImage(named: "MapAnnotationIcon")
        } else {
            pin.image = UIImage(named: "SelectedMapAnnotationIcon")
        }

        if pin == nil {
            pin.canShowCallout = false
        } else {
            pin.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pin
```

and when pin tapped ->

```
  if let annotation = view.annotation as? CustomAnnotation {

        tapControl = !tapControl
        for annotation in mapView.annotations {
            if let annotation = annotation as? MKAnnotation where !annotation.isEqual(selectedAnnotation) {
                mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
        addAnnotations()
        println("tapped")
```

i removed all pins without selected pin, and then draw them back but this time tapcontrol is false so other pins are redrawed with another imageview, so thats what i exactly want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to overrride `isSelected` property inside your `MKAnnotationView` subclass.

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isSelected {
            // do stuff where annotation is selected
        } else {
            // do opposite
        }
    }
}
```